# How do I find the main class in a Java project?

Tags: java

I have downloaded a Java Project from version control -> git

This is the location :

```
https://github.com/kjhulin/CryptokCodeCracker
```

Imported the project into IntelliJ IDE. I tried running it, and it kept prompting to edit the configurations and add a main class.

I'm not sure what the `main class` is. Thanks!

Comment: Look into the `Manifest` file -> `rkccrack.CodeCracker`

Answer (score 2):

Main Class is the class where you have the `main()` method implemented. When you are trying to run a JAR file in a server using command prompt this method will be called from JVM to start the program execution. And this class is searched in `MANIFEST.MF` file where you specify the Main-class.

And when you try to run from eclipse/IntelliJ IDE, you can select the main class and try to run directly.

A main method looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

In your repository, I could see these classes have the main method implemented :

```
Path : CryptokCodeCracker/src/rkccrack/
Files :   CodeCracker.java
          RKCCrack.java
          StreamCrack.java
```

And this is your Manifest file entry :

```
Path : CryptokCodeCracker/Manifest 
Content : Main-Class: rkccrack.CodeCracker
```

Answer (score 0):

in order to run a java program you need to have java installed on your system.you can get it from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk14-downloads.html) and you need to setup java env [link](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/setup) and configure the ide to use the jdk you installed, for that open Intellij and click on files>Project Structure there is a option called Project sdk and you need to specify your jdk installed path.
And to Run this code,you need to navigate to the CodeCracker.java and click on run button here is a photo of my config [image: configuration] hope this helps